# Query Predicate in QueryDSL

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, querydsl

The environment is Java, Spring-boot, Hibernat,  QueryDSL, MySQL.

I have table structure

**Episode**

```
+----+-------------+--------
| id | address_id  | eventno
+----+-------------+--------
|  5 |         27  | F123
|  6 |         30  | F456
|  7 |         45  | F789
+----+-------------+--------

@Entity
public class Episode {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@NotEmpty
private String eventno;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

**Episode_Person**

```
+----+--------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
| id | episode_role | primary_flag | episode_id | person_id |
+----+--------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
| 19 | Buyer        |              |          5 |         1 |
| 20 | Subject      |              |          5 |         2 |
| 23 | Witness      |              |          6 |         3 |
| 24 | Child        |              |          6 |         4 |
| 27 | Buyer        |              |          5 |         3 |
| 63 | Investor     |              |          5 |         4 |
| 64 | Subject      |              |          7 |         1 |
| 65 | Subject      |              |          7 |         3 |

@Entity
public class EpisodePerson {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@Valid
private Person person;

@ManyToOne
private Episode episode;
```

**Person**

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | firstname | surname  |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Clint     | eastwood |
|  2 | Angelina  | joilee   |
|  3 | Brad      | pitt     |
|  4 | Jennifer  | aniston  |

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"nia"}))
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String surname;
private String firstname;
private String gender;
```

So each episode has multiple people. And the join table is Episode_Person.

My UI has a datatable with a filter on each column:

[image]

The filtering already works on Event and Address. And looks like this predicate in QueryDSL:

```
            BooleanBuilder where = new BooleanBuilder();
        if (pagination.getFilterBy().getMapOfFilters().get("eventno")!=null) {
            where.and(qEpisode.eventno.containsIgnoreCase(pagination.getFilterBy().getMapOfFilters().get("eventno")));
        }
        if (pagination.getFilterBy().getMapOfFilters().get("address")!=null) {
            where.and(qEpisode.address.formattedAddress.containsIgnoreCase(pagination.getFilterBy().getMapOfFilters().get("address")));
        }
        where.and(qEpisode.creatingUser.eq(user));
        List<Episode> e = episodeRepository.findAll(where);
```

How would I now add a 3rd predicate for case name where case name is constructed of the first two people returned in the collection of people against a episode?

**UPDATE**

For clarification the DTO thats backs the UI view contains the "casename" attribute. It is created in the service layer when Domain objects are converted to DTO:

```
episodeDashboard.setNames(episodePersonList.get(0).getPerson().getSurname().toUpperCase() +" & " +episodePersonList.get(1).getPerson().getSurname().toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @AlanHay I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily unless you delegate some of the processing to the database.

If we can get the `case_name` property to be populated at the database tier rather than as a derived property in the application logic then the front-end code becomes trivial.

We can do this by means of a view. The exact definition of this will depend on your database however the output would be something like this:

**episode_summary_vw**

```
+------------+-------------------------+
| epsiode_id | case_name               |
+------------+-------------------------+
|  5         |        Eastwood & Joilee| 
|  6         |           Pitt & Aniston| 
|  7         |           Aniston & Pitt| 
+------------+-------------------------+
```

For Oracle it looks like `LISTAGG` function is what you would want and for MySQL the `GROUP_CONCAT` functions. In MySQL then I think this would look something like:

```
CREATE VIEW episode_summary_vw as
SELECT ep.episode_id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.surname SEPARATOR ' & ')
FROM episode_person ep
INNER JOIN person p on p.id = ep.person_id
GROUP BY ep.episode_id;
-- todo: needs limit to first 2 records
```

Once we have a view then we can simply map the case_name to the Episode entity using the `@SecondaryTable` functionality of JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "episodes")
@SecondaryTable(name = "episode_summary_vw", primaryKeyJoinColumna = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="episode_id", reference_column_name="id"))
public class Episode {

    @Column(name ="case_name", table = "episode_summary_vw")
    private String caseName;
}
```

You then filter and sort on the property as for any other field:

```
if (pagination.getFilterBy().getMapOfFilters().get("caseName")!=null) {

    where.and(qEpisode.caseName.containsIgnoreCase(pagination.getFilterBy().
       getMapOfFilters().get("caseName")));
}
```

Comment: Is the view table created for every episode in the database?